# wifi driver issue during Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, dell-inspiron

In my laptop there are two wifi drivers are installed

one is broadcom virtual wireless driver & the other is dell wireless 1704 (802.11b/g/n)

As I checked my pc for Windows 10 update the first one (Broadcom Virtual wireless Adapter is not compatible)

Is dell wireless 1704 us only enough

My Pc is Dell Inspiron 15r & all my other driver is compatible
My Current os is Windows 7 Home Basic

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think that we need a little more clarification on exactly what the issue is?  My guess here being that you have an issue with the Broadcom Virtual Wireless Adapter?

Comment: The solution is simple.  You will need to uninstall the Broadcom virtual wireless driver if you want to use Windows 10 or wait until an update to that driver is released before you upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: I'll try with your recomendation Ramhound. I'll uninstall Broadcom virtual wireless driver y then I comment. greetings